# Is there a cryptography algorithm for signing values with two keys and requiring both to verify it?

Tags: signature, hash-signature

Is there an algorithm that lets me sign a value with two keys at the same time, and in turn requires both keys to verify the signature?

For instance, a scheme could work like this:

- Sign X with Key1 and Key2 at the same time
- Verify X is signed by these two keys

This would be like a joint bank account: to do anything on this account, the bank will require signatures from the two persons that initially created the account together.

I wouldn't bring the value into question, but the goal would be the ability to verify X was signed by two specific parties.

Comment: Is there a reason that signing the value X separate with both keys does not work out? I think you can sign X with k1, then with k2, and for verification, require both signatures to be present.

Comment: It can be done, but I'd have to enforce the verification ie. require both keys -- but if anyone else would check the signed value against k1 only, verification would be ok, while  it was intended to require the k2 as well, right? I was thinking there might be an algorithm that does this out of the box

Comment: Is it really wanted that both (public) keys are required for verification? Isn't what wanted a single common public verification key proving that both private keys have been involved in signing?

Comment: you mind explaining more how this would work? also, to understand this idea better - this approach would mean that we generate an additional key each time whenever we sign a document with k1 and k2? and then this new key can verify the signature?

Comment: "It can be done, but I'd have to enforce the verification ie. require both keys"; actually, you can't force the verifier to do anything; he could accept any signature as valid, or perhaps any signature with exactly 42 '1' bits.

Comment: It's called a multi-signature.

Comment: @Maeher thanks a lot

Comment: @poncho "it can be done" only if it's you who will be verifying it and nobody else